# Rep tab keeps a number balloon after click

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

I clicked the rep tab which has 103 on it. When I clicked, it changed to 4:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This is a bug - surely when it has been clicked it should completely wipe this counter. I didn't get +4 in that instant I clicked it, and when I refreshed that 4 had gone.